# I have a problem while updating my document field in firestore

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a problem related to firestore updating in fields .

```
allow update, delete: if request.auth != null && resource.data.id == request.auth.uid;
```

In the above security rule i am able to update my all documents field except when i change my image array which store link of all my images in storage. if i cannot change images array then update work successfully for me. otherwise permission error occurs on the console and when i call update method all other fields except image array deleted

```
allow update, delete: if request.auth != null;
```

But when i change my security rules to the above line, I did not get permission error and update work successfully. But i don't want to change my security as it is necessary for my application.

My code look like this

```
  let projectData = {
    projectName,
    images,
    
}


await db.collection('projects').doc(projectUid).update(projectData);
```

there is another field of id which added to document when creation so i am not updating it

so anybody knows why error occurs when i am trying to update my images array field ?

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show where you apply this line in your broader set of rules. Also please show why you think this condition is being met by your code `resource.data.id == request.auth.uid`, as we have no way to know that unless you tell us. In general, I recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as following that guidance maximizes the chances someone can help.